# Not able to use GeoPackage as Vector Data Store in Kartoza Geoserver, Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, geoserver

I'm running Kartoza Geoserver v.2.18.0 (Geoserver as Docker image) as an App Service i Azure. Path mappings are set to a File storage and working fine. Kartoza Geoserver 2.20.4 caused some issues with login that most likely was related to path mappings.

With 2.18.0 I'm able to create data stores in geoserver for uploaded shape files, but I'm getting the following error when creating a data store from an uploaded geopackage file.

Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: batch entry 1: [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)

On a local installation of Kartoza Geoserver 2.18.0 running as a docker image in Docker Desktop I can serve an uploaded geopackage without any issues.

Kartoza Geoserver: https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver

Answer (score 1):

The GeoPackage store has seen a number of improvements since 2.18.0. While I cannot be sure it's going to help, it's definitely safer [not to run a version that has known vulnerabilities](https://geoserver.org/vulnerability/2022/04/11/geoserver-2-jiffle-jndi-rce.html), and upgrade to 2.20.4 instead:
https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver/tags

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. We tried with v 2.20.4 first, but had to downgrade to 2.18.0 in order to solve a login issue that was related to path mappings. I will update my post with this info.

Comment: Sorry, the 2.18.x series has been out of support for something like 9 months now... the minimum version receiving any code change is 2.20.x. You might get lucky and find someone that has experienced the same issue as you, and found a workaround, though.